# Recalculate Style: why so stuttering?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, google-chrome

Let's say we have a code that injects series of similar elements into the DOM. Something like this:

```
var COUNT = 10000,
    elements = Object.keys(Array(COUNT).join('|').split('|'));

var d = document, 
    root = d.getElementById('root');

function inject() {
    var count = COUNT,
        ul     = d.createElement('ul'),
        liTmpl = d.createElement('li'),
        liEl   = null;

    console.time('Processing elements');
    while (count--) {
        liEl = liTmpl.cloneNode(false);
        liEl.textContent = elements[count];
        ul.appendChild(liEl);
    }
    console.timeEnd('Processing elements');

    console.time('Appending into DOM');
    root.appendChild(ul);
    console.timeEnd('Appending into DOM');
};
d.getElementById('inject').addEventListener('click', inject);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6D7sM/).

When this snippet is run in Firefox (25.0), the time between calling 'inject' and actually seeing its results more-o-less corresponds to what is logged by `time/timeEnd`. For 1000 elements, about 4 ms; for 10000, about 40 and so on. Quite normal, ain't it?

It's very not so, however, with Chrome (30.0 and Canary 32.0 are tested). While the reported time for processing and appending is actually less than Firefox's, rendering of these elements takes a LOT more.

Puzzled, I've checked the Chrome's profiler for different scenarios - and it turned out the bottleneck is in Recalculate Style action. It takes 2-3 seconds for 10000 nodes, 8 seconds for 20000 nodes, and whopping 17 seconds for 30000 nodes.

---

Now the real question is: has anyone been in the same situation, are there any workarounds?

One possible way we've thought about is limiting the visibility of these nodes in a sort of lazy load ('a sort of', because it's more about 'lazy showing': the elements will already be in place, only their visibility will be limited). It's confirmed that 'Recalculate Style' is triggered only when element is about to become visible (which makes sense, actually).

Comment: Chrome used to be the best browser out there.  Nowadays, not so much.  The other browsers have caught up with Chrome, and Google has apparently put their focus on Chrome for handheld devices.

Comment: Side note as you seem to like tricks : I would use the shorter `Object.keys(Array.apply(0,Array(COUNT)))` instead of `Object.keys(Array(COUNT).join(',').split(','))`.

Comment: Well, I guess I should make this a comment rather than an answer, as it's speculative: I think many of the browsers have optimized "appendChild" for adding a small number of nodes to a single element. However, you might want to try doing the same test with 'innerHTML' - which is more likely optimized in C++ code for adding huge blocks of HTML all at once; like what happens when you load an enormous page. When appending it all with javascript, you're trying to process the browser's work on your own part. (innerHTML is indeed overkill for small additions/changes though)

Comment: @Katana314 [I tested](http://jsfiddle.net/YH4m2/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like the trouble is with the `li` elements that have `display:list-item`

If instead of `ul`/`li` you use `div` elements it works pretty fast in chrome..

Also creating a css rule of `li{display:block;}` fixes the delay.

And manually adding the `list-item` shows the delay even if the elements are already rendered in the DOM (*they have to be re-rendered ofcourse*)

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/6D7sM/1/

(*so it seems that chrome is slow in rendering `display:list-item` elements*)

---

There is also a relevant bug submission to chrome http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71305 which has been merged into http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=%2094248 (*looks like in earlier versions it was crashing chrome, but it has been fixed. the crashing, not the speed*)

Comment: That's tremendously helpful, thank you! I suppose I should submit a bug report for this - at least I see no reasonable explanation why `list-item` elements should be treated in a different way.

Comment: @raina77ow they do have some intrinsic differences to the rest of the elements, such as the bullet/number decoration through CSS counters i assume (*number for `ol` elements*), but disabling those makes no difference, so the problem lies somewhere else..