# Highcharts horrible performance due to "Recalculate Style" and "Layout"

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Lots of similar questions out there but no definitive answer.

- [Highcharts treemap slow rendering upon drilldown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32054706/highcharts-treemap-slow-rendering-upon-drilldown)
- [Recalculate Style: why so stuttering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19796057/recalculate-style-why-so-stuttering)

My previous general question about slow high charts but this question is more specific.

- [Highcharts is much slower rendering a chart after building object vs manually coding same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369567/highcharts-is-much-slower-rendering-a-chart-after-building-object-vs-manually-co?noredirect=1#comment58448675_35369567)

When looking in the chrome "timeline" during the rendering there are 1000's of:

- "recalculate style (highcharts.js:52)"
- "layout (highcharts.js:52)"

Every once in a while I'll find a graph that doesnt have either of those and the performance is amazing.  Also for what ever reason Safari doesnt seem to have any performance issues.

I'm using the following options for highcharts and also tried the boost.js with no success.

```
console.time('Creating Initial Graph');
            // Create Graphs
            $('#cpuGraph').highcharts({

                chart: {
                    type: 'line',
                    //zoomType: 'x',
                    animation: false,
                    shadow: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        enableMouseTracking: true,
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        animation: false,
                        marker: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        turboThreshold: 100
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    animation: false,
                    crosshairs: true,
                    shared: true,
                    valueSuffix: '%',
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    shadow: false,
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        padding: 0
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: times
                },
                yAxis: {
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Trimmed Highcharts drawing points'
                },

                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Using the experimental Highcharts Boost module'
                }



            });
            console.timeEnd('Creating Initial Graph');

            console.time('Converting Data Array to Chart Object');
            var newSeries = [];
            for ( i = 0; i < servers.length; i++) {
                var seria = {};
                seria['name'] = servers[i];
                seria['data'] = cpuArray[i];
                newSeries.push(seria);
            }
            console.timeEnd('Converting Data Array to Chart Object');

            console.time('Creating chart variable');
            var chart = $('#cpuGraph').highcharts();
            console.timeEnd('Creating chart variable');

            console.time('Adding All Chart Objects to Chart');
            $.each(newSeries, function(i){
                console.time("Adding series: " + i);
                chart.addSeries(newSeries[i], false);
                console.timeEnd("Adding series: " + i);
            });

            chart.redraw();
            console.timeEnd('Adding All Chart Objects to Chart');
```

Typical timings:

```
:232 Creating Initial Graph: 778.805ms
:242 Converting Data Array to Chart Object: 0.029ms
:252 Adding series: 0: 1.698ms
:252 Adding series: 1: 0.412ms
:252 Adding series: 2: 0.227ms
:252 Adding series: 3: 0.188ms
:252 Adding series: 4: 0.140ms
:252 Adding series: 5: 0.123ms
:252 Adding series: 6: 0.110ms
:254 Adding All Chart Objects to Chart: 3.374ms
:258 Redraw chart with all objects: 9084.491ms
```

Comment: redrawing took 3ms to me in your code

Comment: It says right there. Redraw: 9084.491ms

Comment: We can continue discussion on the [github](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5039). It really depends on the machine, for example my machine dies with your options, but when creating chart with all option in the place then it takes ~3secs. Note that copy&paste for your data takes a lot of time on my machine... :)